# eth_blockNumber result is always 0x0

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I am running geth/mist on windows 10. geth has been started with

> geth -rpc

I've then waited for the sync to complete (some time) and can confirm the sync is finished with a call to `eth_syncing` which returns:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": 1,
"result": false
}
```

and yet the call to `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}` always returns

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": 83,
"result": "0x0"
}
```

what is going on? docs say this should return the most recent block (even during syncing it should return non zero)

Answer (score 2):

Usually when eth.syncing is false and eth.blockNumber is 0 it means it has not started to synchronize yet. It may take some time until it connects to peers and start synchronizing, usually is just a couple of minutes.

Now by default geth is started in 'fast' mode. This mode has the particularity it will not return valid data until is fully synchronized.

If eth.syncing keeps returning false after more than 15 minutes I'd check if there's some connectivity problem, like a firewall.

Comment: its been on for 2 days and downloaded the blockchain (29 gig) - whilst it was doing that i was checking `eth.syncing` and `currentBlock": "",` was incrementing.. so to say that it hasnt even *started* synchronizing i dont think is accurate

Comment: You didn't say it has downloaded 29 Gb already. That is really odd since eth.blockNumber is 0, it didn't finish to sync, but then eth.syncing should return something. Are you syncing with mainnet? Is your geth version up to date? It happened to me a node may loose all its peers while syncing, and then get stuck, after restarting the node will start syncing again.

Comment: Yes its mainent and geth is the latest version (freshly downloaded) - i have restarted geth many times. i have never seen `eth.blockNumber` return anything else 0 at any stage.

Comment: I have the same issue: Geth
Version: 1.7.0-stable
Git Commit: 6c6c7b2af3efdad4d2f64f70f3a724af434bbcd2
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.9
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.9

32 G down.

Comment: @JZ. As of today the most recent version of geth is [v1.7.2](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases), previous version will not sync to the main chain after the byzantinum fork.

Comment: @Ismael I'm on `1.7.2-stable-1db4ecdc`

Comment: @wal Sorry, but your node has not completed the sync operation. Obvious things to check: Are you syncing in an SSD drive? Do you have enough memory 8Gb+? Are you using the 64 bits version of your OS? Does the firewall allow incoming traffic? Other things to try, but unlikely: reset your router/modem, try a different computer, or different Internet connection.