# sync parity or geth starting from block x

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, synchronization

I'm having issues syncing geth and parity as detailed in [other posts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29414/eth-blocknumber-result-is-always-0x0). What would be ideal is if you could sync starting from the current block only as I dont really need historical blocks anyway.
Is there a way to do this?

i.e. you would provide or 'seed' the information required to mine the next block; take for example [block 4636585](https://etherscan.io/block/4636585)
I'm not sure on the exact technical details (and hence this question) but you would provide geth or parity with the details from a trusted source so it could continue from an arbitrary block number.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Parity allows that.

```
parity --no-ancient-blocks
```

This disables downloading of old blocks after snapshot restoration or warp sync. The result is you start at current best block minus 30_000 historic blocks and will only keep the future blocks without downloading the full history.

**However**, this should not be used in production or on any node that is used to manage any value of Ether or Tokens. Because malicious nodes can easily provide you with tampered snapshots or blocks. **The only way to ensure full integrity of the received data is a full verification of all blocks including ancient blocks**.

Comment: couldnt you just look at the hash of a latest block on several trusted sites to verify the entire chain? if someone sent you a tampered block it would bubble up?

Comment: btw, i had already tried `--no-ancient-blocks` on both main and testnet and i'm still waiting for it to sync, almost a day later.

Comment: Try to increase your `--snapshot-peers`; it should not take more than 30 minutes.